# Por que no coloca el default select?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
<select v-model="select" class="form-control">
                    <option selected="selected">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                    @foreach ($tipo as $t)
                      <option value="{{$t->id_tipo_ajuste}}">{{$t->descripcion}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

estoy utilizando bootstrap, vuejs, laravel, pero cuando quiero utilizar un selected="selected" no me funciona para dejar un valor por defecto, cual es el problema?

Comment: ¿Intentaste así `<option selected>Seleccione una Opción</option>`? No sé de dónde sacas ese `selected="selected"`

Answer (score 0):

prueba con

```html
<select v-model="select" class="form-control">
                    <option selected>Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                    @foreach ($tipo as $t)
                      <option value="{{$t->id_tipo_ajuste}}">{{$t->descripcion}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

También funciona

```html
<select v-model="select" class="form-control">
                    <option selected="">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                    @foreach ($tipo as $t)
                      <option value="{{$t->id_tipo_ajuste}}">{{$t->descripcion}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

Finalmente puedes poner la opción a true

```html
<select v-model="select" class="form-control">
                    <option selected="true">Seleccione una Opcion</option>
                    @foreach ($tipo as $t)
                      <option value="{{$t->id_tipo_ajuste}}">{{$t->descripcion}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
```

Un saludo.

## Fuentes

[Developer.mozilla.org: select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Examples)